# SwaggerUI 3 not respecting `explode: false` for query array parameters in OpenAPI 3 spec

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi

I have a query parameter defined in the OpenAPI 3 spec as follows:

```
      parameters:
      - in: query
        name: categories
        schema:
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
            enum:
            - category1
            - category2
          style: form
          explode: false
```

The expectation is that if I use the "Try it out!" feature and select both category1 and category2, the URL formed should contain:
`?categories=category1,category2`

However, instead SwaggerUI forms that part of the URL as follows:
`?categories=category1&categories=category2`

Thus, it seems that SwaggerUI is treating the parameter as though `explode` is set to `true`.

How can I get SwaggerUI to go with the comma-separated formulation as that's what the server is expecting?

Answer (score 6):

The issue was that the `explode` and `style` properties should have been placed at the same level as `schema`, not nested inside of it.

```
      parameters:
      - in: query
        name: categories
        style: form
        explode: false
        schema:
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
            enum:
            - category1
            - category2
```

Comment: Can you please mark your own answer as the right one? It works, and it is not documented in the swagger docs. This question is a valuable source of information.